# Comparing two strings in Java and seeing unknown characters in the Trace

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver to log into a site and check the date on the page and make sure that the date has been updated to today. I am getting a comparison error that looks like:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<as of[0]3/17/2015> but was:<as of[ ]3/17/2015>
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
at com.example.tests.CubeTime.testCubeTime(CubeTime.java:59)
```

I am not sure where the [0] and the [ ] are coming from. My code for the comparison looks like

```
assertEquals("as of"+datestring,sysDateshort);
```

Comment: It's pretty clear from the error message that there is a difference of the character '0' between the two Strings. Change your expected value to the value that the app is expected to return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets are just there to highlight the difference between what was expected (`[0]`) and what was found (`[ ]`). They are not actually part of either string.

So, in this case, a `0` was expected, but an empty space was found instead.

Comment: wow I can't believe I missed this. My dates were being formatted at 03/17/2015 and 3/15/2015. Thank you for the quick response.